# How to add Shipping method for commerce flat rate module?

Tags: commerce

i am working on drupal commerce's "shipping" part, i want to create two methods for shipping as 
1.Free Shipping 
2.Express 2-day Shipping 
for USA .

For "free shipping" condition is if order total is greater than $100 then we can use "free shipping" else it should apply rate $4.

for "Express 2-day Shipping" condition is if order total is less than $140 then we  can cost $12 else it is free.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module integrates with Drupal Commerce in order to handle this type of requirement. There are many video tutorials available that explain how to setup various shipping rules.

There is also a module called [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) that may be useful if you need to have branching logic in your rules.

In this case I think you would only need two rules:

1. Conditions: type of shipping == "Free shipping" AND order total > $100 Actions: shipping cost = $0
2. Conditions: type of shipping == "Express" AND order total > $140 Actions: shipping cost = $0

You would set the default pricing for the "Free shipping" to $4 and the for the "express" to $12. The default prices would be overridden by the Rules in those two cases.

Comment: its require $ to cents change